# How to update coredata value in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am new in iOS and I am facing a problem regarding to update value of coredata.

For Save

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
 NSManagedObject *device;

                if (self.device) {
                    // Update existing device
                    [device setValue:GlobalIndexPath forKey:@"key"];                                        
                } else {
                    // Create a new device
                    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                    [newDevice setValue:GlobalIndexPath forKey:@"key"];
                }

                NSError *error = nil;
                // Save the object to persistent store
                if (![context save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                }
```

My code to fetch core data is

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

And to update I and using code

```
NSManagedObject* favoritsGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:0];
[favoritsGrabbed setValue:@"1" forKey:@"Key"];
```

Update code not update it add one object.

Note - GlobalIndexPath is a name of string.

But this is not working for me any suggestion. Thanks in Advcance!

Comment: Did you try saving the context?

Comment: @LucasDerraugh Yes I have save it.

Comment: What are you doing in _[self managedObjectContext]_? Please share more code. Are you able to successfully fetch from core data?

Comment: @Adeel Yes I am able to fetch value in NSArray *results.

Comment: I see that you are saving the context after creating new `NSManagedObject`. Are you saving the context __after__ updating?

Comment: @Adeel Did I need to save after update?

Comment: Of course you need to save. Otherwise the changes won't persist.

Comment: @Adeel Ok can you share update code hear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the context every time you make changes to any `NSManagedObject` and want it to persist. Try this:

```
NSManagedObject* favoritsGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:0];
[favoritsGrabbed setValue:@"1" forKey:@"Key"];
NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: I am using same code but the problem is it update but only at index 0 if even I change IndexPath.

Comment: @Muju the code that you have shared clearly updates the first object in `results` array. If you are doing something else then please update your question and provide further details.

Comment: Thank you very much your code work. You save my day.

Comment: Mention not. Cheers.